# How to use USB wifi adapter on a MacBook Pro running on Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I need to create a wifi from the wifi my computer get, I bought a tp link USB adapter, used the USB to USB-c MacBook Pro adapter and connected it to my computer, then I downloaded the drivers but I can't make it work, because I cannot connect the USB wifi adapter to the wifi.

Please could someone help me !

Comment: The MacBook Pro already has Wi-Fi built-in. Are you trying to have the MBP broadcast over two Wi-Fi networks simultaneously, or is the built-in Wi-Fi broken or inoperative?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is called Internet Sharing.

You can not forward your Mac- WiFi to another WiFi, but you can set up sharing.

**Important note:
The one big limitation is that you can’t both be connected to a Wi-Fi network and host a Wi-Fi network at the same time.** So what you are trying to do with the USB WiFi is not possible using your mac-WiFi.

**But** you can use Internet sharing if your Mac is connected to the Internet through an Ethernet adapter.

Enable Internet Sharing and Configure Your Hotspot

The Wi-Fi hotspot option is part of the “Internet Sharing” feature in macOS.

You’ll find it in the System Preferences window.

Click the Apple menu, select System Preferences, and click the Sharing icon. Follow the instructions there.

Comment: There are eithernet to Wifi adapters if you really need to use two wifi networks.